# Debug/Log request for akka-http server

Tags: akka-http

I have the following test http, and I would like to get all the information from the request in the default route.

```
class HttpTestServer(port: Int = 6666)(implicit as: ActorSystem, ec: ExecutionContext, mat: ActorMaterializer)
  extends JsonSupport
  with LazyLogging{

  var numRequest: Int = 0
  def start(): Future[ServerBinding] = {
    def routes = {
      // print request information here
      logRequest("test")
      numRequest += 1
      println(s"HttpServer request received: $numRequest")
      complete(Map("key"-> 1.0))
    }
    Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "0.0.0.0", port)
  }

}
```

And I have the following line at `logback.xml`, to enable the debug at `akka-http`:

```
<logger name="akka.http" level="DEBUG"/>
```

As a references, I am using akka-http [DebuggingDirective](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/debugging-directives/logRequestResult.html#building-advanced-directives)

UPDATED: My guess is that there is a problem with the LoggingAdapter or incompatibility between `LazyLogging` and the akka `LoggingAdapter`. If I print to `stdout` works fine:

```
val logRequestPrintln = DebuggingDirectives.logRequest(LoggingMagnet(_ => println _))
....
logRequestPrintln(complete(Map("key"-> 1.0)))
```